# Trying to prevent server printers on terminal servers

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, printing, terminal, local

We have 4 servers running windows 2008 r2.  We have a separate print server and users are able to connect to and use shared printers.  However the terminal servers appear to create local printers for our 5 xerox printers which error.

I've checked the group policy which is set to prevent printer redirection.

I've checked the users profiles and the printers aren't listed in there.

I've checked the servers connection properties which also show printer redirection as disallowed.

The printers concerned recreate themselves when deleted from file structure and registry using the Terminal server's own ip address as the port.

What am I missing?

Thanks for any help.

Jay

Comment: Did you check the options within the rdp client related to local resources?

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear, whether the *servers connection properties* you referred to are RDP server or RDP client properties.

If that's not the RDP server settings, then I'm guessing that the printers you're talking about were just the client's printers being mapped over RDP.

You may then disallow this features in the RDP server settings. On your server:

1. Open the `Remote Desktop Configuration`
2. Go to `RD Session Host Configuration > RDP-Tcp > Properties`
3. Check both `Client settings` and `Environment` tabs and configure all printer-related features correctly

Hope that's it :)